# How to convert an xlsx file from utf-8 to windows-1252

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, xlsx, windows-1252

I am working on PERL script that reads the data from an .XLSX Excel file and inserts the data into an Oracle database. The database has Windows-1252 encoding, the excel file has UTF-8 encoding(as I know it is the standard at xlsx files) and the special characters such as ö,ü,ű,ő are shown as ??. What is the correct way to convert the encoding of that .xlsx file? I have tried converting the the read string into windows-1252 before it is inserted into the the DB and I have tried convert the whole Excel file into win-1252 but none of them worked.

thank you all for reading it and trying help solve my problem.
Regards,
Krisz

Comment: Show what you've tried? Especially the *converting the read string into windows-1252 before it is inserted into the DB* approach.

Comment: You can use `Encode::to_from($str, 'UTF-8', 'cp1252')`, to convert an UTF-8 encoded `$str` to Windows-1252 in-place, see [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode#from_to)

Comment: Which perl module do you use to access Oracle-DB?

Answer (score 0):

> The database has Windows-1252 encoding

The longer-term solution is to fix that so that the database encoding is UTF8.

In the meantime, you could parse your XML string using XML::LibXML and then serialise it to an alternative encoding, like this:

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml);
$doc->setEncoding('ascii');
my $ascii_xml = $doc->toString();
```

Any non-ASCII character in the XML will then get converted to a numeric character entity with no loss of data, e.g.: `<title>Café life</title>` will become `<title>Caf&#233; life</title>`.

If you can't put UTF-8 XML in the database, then I would suggest there is no particular advantage to using windows-1252 instead of ASCII, and using ASCII eliminates a number of potential "foot-guns".